# Hibernate: Disable logging to console WITHOUT log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I have hibernate and I would like to decrease the logging that happens in console everytime it runs. I do not have log4j in my application nor do I want to add it in.

Here is an example of the logs I get everytime I run my app

```
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=Sidney, password=****}
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:43 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:43 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Feb 25, 2014 6:36:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<!--         <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateDB</property> -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">**</property>
        <property name="connection.password">**</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
<!--         <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->

<!--         <mapping class="edu.cs157b.hibernate.Student"/> -->
        <mapping class="edu.cs157b.hibernate.Doctor"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your log details I understood that hibernate version is- Hibernate 4.0.4.Final.**Since version 4.0**, Hibernate has used the **JBoss logging library** and so even your application does not contain any log4j still hibernate is using JBoss logging provider as default provider.
For more please go through this link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html

Hope this info will help you to understand why logs are still available without any log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable all Logger functions using java.util.logging :

```
private void disableLogging() {
  LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
  Logger logger = logManager.getLogger("");
  logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE); //could be Level.OFF
}
```

It would affect any other Logger you're using, but in some cases may be useful.